Merge two queries/interfaces into one
I have two queries of which I need to create one, unified without any filters applied on them. The code for each is as below
The query1, which consist of 5400 rows
First Table Data



Date
InvoiceDate
DocumentID
SalesId
Value




01/01/2024
02/01/2024
DocId001
SalesId001
100


05/01/2024
06/01/2024
DocId001
SalesId001
150


10/02/2024
10/02/2024
DocId002
SalesId002
50



  no sufficient data from d365

Second query, which consist of 6000 rows



Date
InvoiceDate
DocumentID
SalesId
Value




01/01/2024
02/01/2024
DocId001
SalesId001
100


05/01/2024
06/01/2024
DocId001
SalesId001
150


10/02/2024
10/02/2024
DocId002
SalesId002
50




  no sufficient data from d365


Expected result from a query (I've been told to not use union)



Date
Value
SalesInvoiceID
SalesOrderID




01/01/2024
100
DocId001
SalesId001


05/01/2024
150
DocId001
SalesId001


05/02/2024
80
DocId004
SalesId004


08/01/2024
200
DocId003
SalesId003


10/02/2024
50
DocId002
SalesId002



As you can see, they share lot of tables. Because of filter applied, there are rows which are available in query1 but not query2 and vice versa,
What I've done so far is to create unified view on two ways, and here is the result
way1:
    
  no sufficient data from d365


way2:
    no sufficient data from d365

I am not sure which way is better and which is more accurate (I keen to 1st method and would prefer that) but I am not sure if its properly created, and whats more important - how to check if it is accurate to be honest.
Any ideas in how to merge two queries into one and how to test the accuracy would be highly appreciated

It's hard to debug code without data from here.
If you need to mix 2 queries you can use the UNION operator.
Make sure that both queries have the same columns and that they are of both types, in case you don't have a way to get the values, you can leave the missing columns with empty values and the name of the column
SELECT column1, column2, NULL as column3 from table1
UNION 
SELECT column1, NULL as column2, column3 from table2 ;


Hi. I added a bit of the data. I've been told to not use UNION although that was my go-to as well. Could you please help me to arrange an elegant SELECT statement with joins?

Hello
Now with data the logic of the problem is clearer, You have something like a relationship between an order document and an invoice document.
But both come from the same table in the ERP and by default no filters are used.
You can:

Add the name of the erp as a tag to this question, it seems to be Microsoft dynamics, someone with more experience may find the doubt.
search for similar questions in the stackoverflow community, there are results if you search for the CustInvoiceTrans table.
Study the dynamics model in the official documentation called Common Data Model.


I would like to help you but I do not have a dynamics system to test the queries.
